# how to enable subsite navigation on the parent site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I create a Site called Ferrari. I created one new site in that. I think generally when we create any new site under parent site, the child site must be appear as second tab for the parent site. But it is not appearing. But when i see in the **view all site content** then that sub site is appearing. How to enable navigation to that child site in the parent site.
See the below images for understanding.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should activate publishing feature, then go to the **site settings -> look and feel -> navigation**. In the **Global Navigation** section you should check **show subsites** checkbox.